# The numpy.triu does not work, tri() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, triangular

the code is :

```
adjj = np.triu(self.adj,k=1)
```

then Pycharm stopped and reported :

> File "D:/mapgeneralization/rastertest/dbscan.py", line 436, in
> **init**
> adjj = np.triu(self.adj,k=1)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\twodim_base.py",
> line 465, in triu
> mask = tri(*m.shape[-2:], k=k-1, dtype=bool) TypeError: tri() missing 1 required positional argument: 'N'

Comment: my matrix is a huge sparse matrix, the triu() should use scipy.sparse.triu() function, the numpy triu() function of course does not work. the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

What is `self.adj`?  I get this error message if I use a scalar argument:

```
In [420]: np.triu(3, k=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-420-860353c7169f>", line 1, in <module>
    np.triu(3, k=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in triu
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py", line 499, in triu
    mask = tri(*m.shape[-2:], k=k-1, dtype=bool)
TypeError: tri() missing 1 required positional argument: 'N'
```

but no error is I give it a 2d array:

```
In [421]: np.triu(np.ones((3,4)), k=1)
Out[421]: 
array([[0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

As with many `numpy` functions, `triu` starts with

```
m = asanyarray(m)
```

If `m` is something like a scipy sparse matrix, the result is a 0d object dtype array.  Argumentwise this will be the same as my scalar example.